# sql server 2005 replication article conflict

Tags: sql-server, database-replication

I have a sql server 2005 database that I want to setup replication for. The problem is that the database has two schemas both of which have a table with the same name in it.

For some reason even though the tables are in different schemas the replication creation fails when done through management studio due to conflicting article names (i assume its trying to create the same name for both tables in the different schemas).

Is there any workaround for doing this in the studio, I can probably write a script or program to do this but just for this one thign is a bit annoying and it probably wont be allowed to run in production.

Perhaps there is a hot fix or something I'm not aware about?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a way around this purely using the new publication wizard in SSMS - the article name is always the table name without a schema-qualifier, and can't be customised from the wizard - although there is a work-around if you use the scripting options.

Go through the wizard as normal, but at the end of the process, untick the "create publication" option and select the "Generate script file..." option.

Once the file is created, open it and edit the article names so that they no longer conflict, then execute the script in the publication database.

Comment: Will altering the Article Property - Description when selecting articles during the publication wizard have any impact on this working successfully?

Answer (score 0):

could you think of having two publications for your database, each publication being linked to one of the schemas? Of course, this means that you'll have to define two different subscribers, one for each publication. The feasability of this proposal will of course highly depend on how you need to distribute your data among the subscribers, and on the way your users access the data